# How to configure MaaS clusters？

Tags: 14.04, maas, cluster

When I log in to MaaS and configure clusters I get this error:

[image]

I want to know how to configure clusters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The error page is showing you the problem:

- Note that static and dynamic IP ranges may not overlap
- You have a dynamic IP range between `127.170.0.1` and `127.170.0.100`
- And a static IP range starting at `127.170.0.99`

You must define/change the ranges and try to install again.

---

Documentation for `MAAS` is at: https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.2/en/